# Get data from Big Object in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, big-object

Due to storage limitation I need to think of a way to archive/reduce the storage for orders and order line items. I was thinking of Big Objects, but I need to be able to use the data from Orders and Order Line Items in the Marketing Cloud Campaigns.

Do you know if is possible for Marketing Cloud to create DE from Big Object records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Big Objects nor External Objects are supported in MC Connector. You would need to create a custom data pipeline using either API or, depending on  volumes an and latency requirements, CSV/SFTP approach for batch updates of data extensions in SFMC.

Comment: Thank you ... back to the drawing board